# Google Sheet Formula for finding an element across multiple tabs

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I`m trying to populate values in column F, "Product Sold Date" in "TABLES" tab

Basically... the logic is as follows:

```
    1) If Column C (Product Status) = "Paused", then return "Paused"
    2) If Product start date = NULL or Product end date = NULL, then return NULL
    3) If Product start date < today`s date, then return "No Data"
    4) If Product start date >= today`s date, return "Upcoming"
    5) If product End date <= today`s date, return "Ended"
    6) If product start date <= today`s date, return "In Market"
7) If the condition does not belong to any of the above cases, then return the actual Product launch dates
```

Below is the link to the sample data I`m working on..

I`m pasting the link itself, becaues there are multiple tabs included

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120rHOt8Pa_PdMKPgLkSYOKTO2Cv1hBH6PpTrg7FfJLk/edit?usp=sharing

Ultimately, I need to populate the actual "Product Launch Date" by scanning data in each tab

I tried using nested if statements with combination of Index Match. 
But I`m totally lost in case of multiple tabs

Can anyone please provide suggestion on this?

Should we think about using query statements instead in this case?

Sidenote: The returned values will be mix of dates and character 
[In market/ Ended/ Upcoming/ No Data/ NULL/ Paused/ Actual Date]

Comment: there is a conflict in **3)** and **7)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(C2:C="Paused", C2:C,
 IF((A2:A="")+(B2:B=""), ,
 IF(A2:A >= TODAY(), "Upcoming",
 IF(B2:B <= TODAY(), "Ended",
 IF(A2:A  = TODAY(), "In Market", 
 IF(E2:E<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D&E2:E, 
 {'Eaton Centre'!A2:A &"Eaton Centre",  'Eaton Centre'!B2:B;
  'Yorkdale Mall'!A2:A&"Yorkdale Mall", 'Yorkdale Mall'!B2:B; 
  'Vaughan Mills'!A2:A&"Vaughan Mills", 'Vaughan Mills'!B2:B}, 2, 0)), )))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the help!!, I figured these out :)

Answer (score 1):

Your formula would be

```
=IF(C2="Paused",C2,if(OR(A2="",B2=""),"",IF(A2<TODAY(),"No Data",IF(A2>=TODAY(),"Upcoming",IF(B2<=TODAY(),"Ended",IF(A2<=TODAY(),"In Market","Actual Product Launch dates"))))))
```

In the above formula, you should be using a Query formula in place of "Actual Product Launch dates", to extract the actual date.

But the points 3 & 6 don't make any sense. The 6th condtion should be `If product start date = todays date, return "In Market"`

Comment: I`m going to further clarify this question actually... it is very confusing